# Where is .bowerrc file in a Yeoman generated Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm looking through [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/) which might be outdated that mentions a .bowerrc file after running `yo angular`.  But for me, the .bowerrc file is missing. I couldn't find sources say that it's no longer in use. So if I still need it, where can I get it?

---

Update: The reason I didn't have .bowerrc was because my `yo angular` did not run to completion due to errors. [It has been fixed since](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21842263/3290121).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create in your root a .bowerrc file with that content

```
 {
      "directory": "app/components",
      "json": "bower.json" // Add this line
  }
```

All packages will be installed in that directory. Then create a file bower.json with that content

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": "",
  "description": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.0",
    "angular": "~1.2.13",
    "angular-resource": "~1.2.13",
    "angular-route": "~1.2.13"
  }
}
```

and run it with node prompt `bower install`

I hope will hepls you

Answer (score 2):

I think that setting line mentioned above

```
  "json": "bower.json" // Add this line
```

Isn't necessary; check the Bower [configuration](http://bower.io/docs/config/) page.

Comment: That's correct. By not declaring the `json` path in the bowerrc file it defaults to bower.json.