# Yo angular error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm attempting to build Angular via Yeoman with the command

"yo angular"

everything works until I get to the tmp directory:

```
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10021-myBKjnB0'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10021-myBKjnB0']
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES, mkdir \'/home/colin/tmp/npm-10021-myBKjnB0\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10021-myBKjnB0' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin/Desktop/ang-news
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /home/colin/tmp/npm-10021-myBKjnB0
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10021-myBKjnB0'
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-jshint
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-svgmin
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-rev
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jshint-stylish
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/colin/Desktop/ang-news/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:55
  if (_.isString(componentConfigFile.main)) {
                                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at findMainFiles (/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:55:37)
    at /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:101:17
    at forOwn (/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:1301:15)
    at Function.forEach (/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:2595:9)
    at detect (/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/lib/detect-dependencies.js:300:5)
    at module.exports (/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/wiredep/wiredep.js:39:39)
    at Generator._injectDependencies (/home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/app/index.js:277:5)
    at /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
    at /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:113:21
    at /home/colin/npm/lib/node_modules/generator-angular/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:16
colin@Studio-XPS-1640:~/Desktop/ang-news$ npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10035-irWQWzi0'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10035-irWQWzi0']
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES, mkdir \'/home/colin/tmp/npm-10035-irWQWzi0\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10035-irWQWzi0' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-37-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-karma" "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" "karma-ng-scenario" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /home/colin/Desktop/ang-news
npm ERR! node -v v0.11.10-pre
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /home/colin/tmp/npm-10035-irWQWzi0
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/home/colin/tmp/npm-10035-irWQWzi0'
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-karma
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/karma-ng-scenario
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/colin/Desktop/ang-news/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm assuming that this is an error with permissions, but you cannot run yo commands with sudo because it is a separate user.

I changed the permissions of /usr/local with chown, but I'm not sure if this affects my issue.

Comment: did you installed yeoman globally with -g flag ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My /home/colin/tmp had wrong permissions. It happened because I did sudo npm install in the past, and npm doesn't handle this well enough.

```
sudo chown colin /home/colin/tmp -R
```

The above changes all of the permissions to the user colin for the tmp folder.

Answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21842301/3172050